# Join two tables and concatenate same column names in same statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a large raw data table. It's long and I'm trying to sort of transpose it. I'm joining two select statements from within it. As such I get multiple columns with the same name. It's a full outer join and I would like to have the two separate columns of the same name as one column. Since it is an outer join I don't want to pick just one tables column for it either like select t1.c1

Thanks!

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT * FROM [LabData].[dbo].[FermHourlyDCSData] where Attribute='Urea') P
  full outer JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM [LabData].[dbo].[FermHourlyDCSData] where Attribute='Water to Mash Total Water') FPD ON 
P.[TimeStamp] = FPD.[TimeStamp] 
and P.Site = FPD.Site
and P.Element = FPD.Element
```

Actual:

```
Site Attribute Timestamp Value Site Attribute Timestamp Value
AD   Urea      1/1/2019  127   Null Null      Null      Null
Null Null      Null      Null  AD   Water     1/1/2019  7.5
```

Expected/Desired:

```
Site Attribute Timestamp Value Value
AD   Urea      1/1/2019  127  Null
AD   Water     1/1/2019  Null 7.5
```

Comment: Have you had a look at [`ISNULL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)/[`COALESCE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and limiting your columns in your `SELECT` by not using `*`? if not, what have you tried to get the resultset you are after and why didn't it work/provide the result you were after?

Comment: So then something like Select isnull(t1.c1,t2.c1)? wonder if that works? I'll try it.

Comment: Will UNION ALL between tables solve the issue rather than joining tables?

Comment: The issue with union all is that i also want to make a new column for each selected for the value column. Even if I alias the column in each select with a different name it doesnt work. I thin union and union all only work if all the columns are of the same name in each table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it's not very pretty, but it does work:

```
SELECT 
[Site] = ISNULL(P.[Site], FPD.[Site]),  
[Attribute] = ISNULL(P.[Attribute], FPD.[Attribute]),   
[Timestamp] =   ISNULL(P.[Timestamp], FPD.[Timestamp]), 
[Value] =   ISNULL(P.[Value], FPD.[Value]), 
[Element] =ISNULL(P.[Element], FPD.[Element])
FROM (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[FermHourlyDCSData] where Attribute='Urea') P
full outer JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[FermHourlyDCSData] where Attribute='Water to Mash Total Water') FPD ON 
P.[TimeStamp] = FPD.[TimeStamp] 
and P.Site = FPD.Site
and P.Element = FPD.Element
```

Comment: Thanks guys those were all great responses. I may need to do some nested isnulls though as I actually want to do this with more than a join between just 2 tables and isnull only accepts 2 arguments. Is there a more efficient way you can think of than that?

Comment: You could potentially use a CASE WHEN ELSE

Answer (score 1):

ISNULL is what you should use for this

```
ISNULL(p.Site,fpd.Site) as [Site]
```

Comment: I can't comment on your question above "Thanks guys those were all great responses. I may need to do some nested isnulls though as I actually want to do this with more than a join between just 2 tables and isnull only accepts 2 arguments. Is there a more efficient way you can think of than that?" ...

Comment: check out coalesce :) similar to isnull but with more than just two items

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but you seem to want a much simpler query:

```
select Site, Attribute, Timestamp,
       (case when Attribute = 'Urea' then Value end) as value_u,
       (case when Attribute = 'Water to Mash Total Water' then Value end) as value_2
from [LabData].[dbo].[FermHourlyDCSData]
where Attribute  in ('Urea', 'Water to Mash Total Water')
```